# Getting object as singleArrayObject, how to convert in NSMutableArray?

Tags: objective-c, json, nsmutablearray, nsarray

in response, i am getting `gas_cylinders` key as single array object

```
"gas_cylinders":["[{\"quantity\":\"2\",\"name\":\"Medium Blue\",\"price\":\"100.0\",\"total_price\":\"200.0\"},{\"quantity\":\"3\",\"name\":\"Green\",\"price\":\"100.0\",\"total_price\":\"300.0\"},{\"quantity\":\"1\",\"name\":\"Dark Green\",\"price\":\"100.0\",\"total_price\":\"100.0\"}]"]
```

Note:- `tripDictionary` contain below data..

```
(lldb) po tripDictionary 
{
    "gas_cylinder_total" = 600;
    "gas_cylinders" =     (
        "[{\"quantity\":\"2\",\"name\":\"Medium Blue\",\"price\":\"100.0\",\"total_price\":\"200.0\"},{\"quantity\":\"3\",\"name\":\"Green\",\"price\":\"100.0\",\"total_price\":\"300.0\"},{\"quantity\":\"1\",\"name\":\"Dark Green\",\"price\":\"100.0\",\"total_price\":\"100.0\"}]"
    );
}
```

i am taking `gas_cylinders` like below way..

```
NSArray *arr = [tripDictionary valueForKey:@"gas_cylinders"];
if (arr && arr.count > 0) {
   NSLog(@"first obj = %@",arr[0]);
}
```

output of above `NSLog` like..

```
first obj = [{"quantity":"2","name":"Medium Blue","price":"100.0","total_price":"200.0"},{"quantity":"3","name":"Green","price":"100.0","total_price":"300.0"},{"quantity":"1","name":"Dark Green","price":"100.0","total_price":"100.0"}]
```

how can i get this object in `NSMutableArray` ?

Comment: Please update your question showing where `tripDictionary` comes from.

Comment: @rmaddy updated

Comment: Please don't post pictures of text, post actual text. It's easier to read, it's searchable, and the text can be referenced.

Comment: @rmaddy okay edited

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The data is not what you think it is. The value of the `gas_cylinders` key is an array of JSON string.

```
NSArray *cylinders = tripDictionary[@"gas_cylinders"];
NSString *firstCylinder = cylinders[0];
```

At this point, `firstCylinder` is a JSON string. You need to parse that JSON string to get the desired array of dictionaries contained in the JSON string.

Comment: thanks.. after your given answer, converted into NSArray and get desired output... `NSData* data = [firstCylinder dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
                NSArray *values = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:nil];`